# Select data from specific year

Tags: java, sql, ejb-3.0

I need a solution for my problem here.

I got 2 tables, assetdetail and assetcondition. Here is the structure of those tables.

```
assetdetail
-----------------------------------------------------------
| sequenceindex | assetcode | assetname | acquisitionyear |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| 1             | 110       | Car       | 2012-06-30      |
| 2             | 111       | Bus       | 2013-02-12      |


assetcondition
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|sequenceindex | indexassetdetail | fiscalyear | assetamount | assetprice |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1            |          1       |  2012      | 1           | 20000000   |
| 2            |          1       |  2013      | 1           | 15000000   |
| 3            |          2       |  2013      | 1           | 25000000   |
```

And i want the result is like this:

```
------------------------
assetname | assetprice |
------------------------
   Car    |  20000000  |
   Bus    |  25000000  |
```

Note: using "`SELECT WHERE fiscalyear =` "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without explaining how your tables are linked one can only guess. Here's the query I came up with.

```
select assetdetail.assetname,
   sum( assetcondition.assetprice )

 from assetdetail
inner join assetcondition
   on assetcondition.indexassetdetail = assetdetail.sequenceindex

where assetcondition.fiscalyear = 2013
group by assetdetail.assetname;
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't understand from a logical point of view your query. By the way the operator that you have to you use is the JOIN's one.
The SQL that follows, I don't know if it is what you want.

```
    Select assetname, assetprice
From assetdetail as ad join assetcondition as ac on (as.sequenceindex = ac.sequenceindex)
Where fiscalyear = '2013'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if it is what you're looking for, but I guess what you want is a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    assetdetail.assetname, assetcondition.assetprice
FROM
    assetdetail
JOIN
    assetcondition
ON
    assetdetail.sequenceindex = assetcondition.sequenceindex
WHERE
    YEAR(acquisitionyear) = '2013'
```